# how to handle the url with many special characters

Tags: urls

I have a url like this `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzU3OTc1MDM1Mg==&mid=2247500792&idx=1&sn=7d6d688ce9cdb4f1a60b43f97163efe1&chksm=fd63d347ca145a51cbf42519a256ecbeafaaec40cc74c5ac96e481d747eaf094105e1db3fd72&scene=21#wechat_redirect`, this url contains some special characters. when I using this command to render it:

```
\url{https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzU3OTc1MDM1Mg==&mid=2247500792&idx=1&sn=7d6d688ce9cdb4f1a60b43f97163efe1&chksm=fd63d347ca145a51cbf42519a256ecbeafaaec40cc74c5ac96e481d747eaf094105e1db3fd72&scene=21#wechat_redirect}
```

it could not works. what should I do to handle the special charactors without add `\` one by one? it it possible to eacape the special charactors batch?

Comment: Works for me. Make a complete example and describe what you mean by "not works".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\url{https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzU3OTc1MDM1Mg==&mid=2247500792&idx=1&sn=7d6d688ce9cdb4f1a60b43f97163efe1&chksm=fd63d347ca145a51cbf42519a256ecbeafaaec40cc74c5ac96e481d747eaf094105e1db3fd72&scene=21#wechat_redirect}
\end{document}
```

[image]